# Find a specific word inside file and delete its line

Tags: c++, file, overwrite

As the title suggests I am trying to find a specific word inside a file, and then deleting the line including it, but what I do here destroys the content of the file:

```
cin>>ID; //id of the line we want to delete
ifstream read;
read.open("infos.txt"); 
ofstream write; 
write.open("infos.txt");
while (read >> name >> surname >> id) {
    if (ID != id) {
        write << name << " " << surname << " " << id << endl; 
    }
    else write << " ";
    }
    read.close();
    write.close();
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide more detail than "this doesn't work" - see [mcve]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both of your files have same name. Calling basic_ofstream::open destroys content of a file if it already exists. In your case you destroyed data in input file before doing anything. Use different name and later rename. I assume line in input is ended with "\n" so we can use getline(). Then we need to tell if word is present in line and for that there is [this function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find). std::string:npos is returned if line doesn't contain word.

```
#include <cstdio> // include for std::rename
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

void removeID() {
    std::string ID;
    cin >> ID; //id of the line we want to delete
    ifstream read("infos.txt");
    ofstream write("tmp.txt"); 
    if (read.is_open()) {
       std::string line;
       while (getline(read, line)) {
          if (line.find(ID) != std::string::npos)
             write << line;
       }
    } else {
       std::cerr << "Error: coudn't open file\n";
       /* additional handle */
    }

    read.close();
    write.close();
    std::remove("infos.txt");
    std::rename("tmp.txt", "infos.txt");
}
```

Comment: so there isn't there any way to delete from the same file ?

Comment: why do you need it? you end up with updated file with same name as old one

Comment: This method works perfectly too, I asked before seeing the edit

Comment: Glad i could help ^_^. You should mark this question as answered then